# Pulseaudio producing irregular audio inside ECS fargate

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, pulseaudio

I am running a ubuntu docker container inside ECS fargate and I'm using pulseaudio to record audio, but the audio output is irregular. Any suggestions on how to deal with this issue?
If I need to pass the sound card to docker as a device, how can I find the soundcard path for ECS fargate?